# How can I add a progress bar in powerpoint that excludes the last slides

Tags: vba, powerpoint

Basically I want to add a progress bar to my powerpoint that does not cover the entire presentation. However I have some additional slides that I might not need when presenting and therefore want to exclude from the progress bar.

```
Sub AddProgressBar()
    On Error Resume Next
        With ActivePresentation
              sHeight = .PageSetup.SlideHeight - 12
              n = 0
              j = 0
              For i = 1 To .Slides.Count
                If .Slides(i).SlideShowTransition.Hidden Then j = j + 1
              Next i:
              For i = 2 To .Slides.Count
                .Slides(i).Shapes("progressBar").Delete
                If .Slides(i).SlideShowTransition.Hidden = msoFalse Then
                  Set slider = .Slides(i).Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, 0, sHeight, (i - n) * .PageSetup.SlideWidth / (.Slides.Count - j), 12)
                  With slider
                      .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = ActivePresentation.SlideMaster.ColorScheme.Colors(ppFill).RGB
                      .Name = "progressBar"
                  End With
                Else
                   n = n + 1
                End If
              Next i:
        End With
End Sub

Sub RemoveProgressBar()
    On Error Resume Next
        With ActivePresentation
              For i = 22 To .Slides.Count
              .Slides(i).Shapes("progressBar").Delete
              .Slides(i).Shapes("pageNumber").Delete
              Next i:
        End With
End Sub
```

This is what I did so far but it shows an unfinished progress bar ad the 'final' slide that includes the progress bar.

Comment: So you're using the slide's Hidden property to determine if the progress bar should be added or not. So if there are slides you don't need, you will mark them as hidden? If not, you need a second custom property (tag perhaps) to indicate if the progress bar should be applied or not. I'm not sure what you actually need. Do you just want the progress bar to not appear on the last slide?

Comment: No I don't want hidden slides since I might need them. So I just want the progress bar to be finished after 20 slides but then there will follow some additional slides. I hope you can help me!

Answer (score 0):

Replace .Slides.Count with the index of the last slide you want the progress bar to appear on. You could make it dynamic by using InputBox to enter the value.